# How to make linked list of tables in Java?

Tags: java, collections, linked-list

I am new in java and I do not know I think right or not about what I want to do. I want to create a linked list of tables so I create a class that make a 2D-array and in another class I make an instance of it for each node of list, but I do not know how should I point to class to have something like linked list and how can I sometimes remove one instance and point to previous instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the `List<T>` abstraction: the `List` interface defines all the list-y things that you need.  The `T` in this case is Java generics: a `List` can hold any reference type, be it `String`, `Person`, or `Table`.

Since a 2D array is an object, you're free to create a `List` that contains them.   A better idea would be to encapsulate that implementation detail inside another class of your own making.

The best way to learn how to do it would be to look at the source code for the `LinkedList` that's already built into Java.

Comment: In this case can I access one of the object of the list and for example add something to table or edit the object?

Comment: That's true in all cases.  Lists just hang onto references.  You're free to access and modify them any way you wish.